# array operation results differ between interactive and the program

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, operation

> I compare two arrays interactively in iPython, the returns are
>   correct:
>
> In[143]: r=np.array([0.,0.04166667, 0.08333333, 0.125, 0.16666667 ,
>   0.20833333 , 0.25, 0.29166667 , 0.33333333 , 0.375, 0.41666667,0.45833333 , 0.5, 0.54166667, 0.58333333 , 0.625, 0.66666667 , 0.70833333 , 0.75,     0.79166667, 0.83333333,  0.875, 0.91666667, 0.95833333])
>
> ```
> In[144]: c=np.array([ 0., 0.04166667, 0., 0., 0., 0.20833333, 0., 0.29166667 , 0., 0.  , 0., 0.45833333, 0.,        0.54166667, 0. , 0. , 0.,0.70833333, 0. , 0.79166667 , 0., 0., 0., 0.95833333])
>
> In [145]: c==r
>
> Out[145]: 
> array([ True,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False,
>        False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False,  True,
>        False,  True, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool
> ```

)

But in a python program in the 'same' setting, the results are not correct:

```
turns=1

r = np.linspace(1/24, turns, 24*turns,endpoint=False)

rr=r%1 

c=np.array([0.,0.04166667,0,0,0,0.20833333,0,0.29166667,0,0,0,0.45833333,
0,0.54166667,0,0,0,0.70833333,0,0.79166667,0,0,0,0.95833333])

cc=np.tile(c,turns)

print([rr==cc])
```

The result is different:

```
[array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)]
```

What mistake did I made? 
Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with floating point precision; your first and second case are really **not the same**. The [Floating Point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/) is a useful resource here.

In the first instance, you're populating two arrays from floating point literals and then comparing them directly. In the second, you're using *the output of a numpy function* and directly comparing that against the second array which is still created from literals.

Even though the **displayed** version of the function output looks the same, the actual numbers have more precision than that, and that's enough to throw off the `==` comparison; you should (almost) never be using equality comparison for floats in the first place.

A quick example:

```
>> print 0.1 + 0.2
0.3
>> 0.1 + 0.2
0.30000000000000004
```

Answer (score 1):

As answered this is a floating point issue. One solution is to use [`np.isclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html):

```
In [11]: np.isclose(rr, cc)
Out[11]:
array([ True,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False,
       False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False,  True,
       False,  True, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

---

This checks whether values are within atol of each other (by default 1e-8):

```
In [12]: cc[1]
Out[12]: 0.041666670000000003

In [13]: rr[1]
Out[13]: 0.041666666666666664

In [14]: cc[1] == rr[1]
Out[14]: False

In [15]: rr[1] + 1e-8 > cc[1]
Out[15]: True
```